# How do I output loops to a text file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, loops, text

I have searched for this a lot and most articles relating to this are about php  and python. However they were not actually answering my question.WHEN I OPEN A TEXT FILE I WANT TO BE ABLE TO SEE THE OUTPUT THERE.I have already tried the method below. The code ran with no errors but it didn't output to the file "filename".

```
def this()
  i = 0
  until i>=20
    i += 1
    next unless (i%2)==1
    puts i
  end
end 

filename = ARGV
script = $0
that = puts this
txt = File.open(filename,'w')
txt.write(that)
txt.close()*
```

Comment: You will be more likely to get a helpful answer if you indent your code and explain what you are trying to do in more detail.

Comment: how are you running this program?

Comment: I run it in windows cmd with #ruby my_file.ruby another_file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sequence of your code is a little bit wrong.

You should instead;

1. Do whatever you want e.g. process ARGV (This step is fine)
2. Open the file - this returns you the file handler
3. Pass the file handler to the `this` function
4. Write the content
5. Close the file

**Example:**

```
def this(file)
  i = 0
  until i>=20
    i += 1
    next unless (i%2)==1
    file.puts(i)
  end
end 

# Main
begin
  file = File.open('hello.txt','w')
  this(file)
rescue IOError => e
  puts "oops"
ensure 
  file.close()
end
```

**Output:**

> 1 
>   3 
>   5 
>   7 
>   9 
>   11 
>   13 
>   15 
>   17 
>  
>   19

You should also be capturing potential IO errors, this is a fairly common practise.

Comment: This worked....wow though I am actually new to using that exception handling... I will take sometime to study the anatomy of the codes....puts "Thank you"

Comment: ...I don't think I have the privy to do so now cos am new? if not....kindly direct on how to.

Comment: @Dlaw u should be able to do it without privilege. It is just a tick I'm grey beside the solution u want to endorse. Just click it and it will turn green. Give me a shout if it is sill not clear. Thanks

Comment: @Dlaw for accepting an answer, please refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
def this(file)
  i = 0
  until i>=20
    i += 1
    next unless (i%2)==1
    # Normally 'puts' writes to the standard output stream (STDOUT)
    # which appears on the terminal, but it can also write directly
    # to a file ...
    file.puts i
  end
end

# Get the file name from the command line argument list. Note that ARGV
# is an array, so we need to specify that we want the first element
filename = ARGV[0]

# Open file for writing
File.open(filename, 'w') do |file|
  # call the method, passing in the file object
  this(file)
  # file is automatically closed when block is done
end
```